# Converting site for Retina-resolution screens

Tags: css

Apple's new [Macbook Pro](http://www.apple.com/uk/macbook-pro/) has a 15" screen with a resolution of 2880x1800. At present it's scaling websites resulting in pixel-doubled images and a layout which appears double-scaled too.

As a web developer how do I go about converting my existing PHP/XHTML/CSS website to take advantage of high-DPI screens?

Comment: You could end up making things so small that people without perfect vision may have difficulties.

Comment: My aim isn't to make things smaller. I want to double their resolution whilst preserving physical size. As Apple have done on their website when viewed at Retina resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following page offers a decent run-through:

http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/make-sure-your-site-looks-good-on-the-new-retina-macbook-pro/

Icon fonts provide one solution, and the @media types allow additional styles to be used:

Example:

```
@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .logo {
        background: url(/path/to/my/highreslogo.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100px 100px;
        /* rest of your styles... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Just made a site retina friendly, used the above media query (similar) and it worked like a dream.

Answer (score 4):

This script might help - http://retinajs.com/. You add @2x to your image names cut for retina display and the script does the rest. One pitfall when cutting the images is that everything must be divisible by two - which you already know, but this tripped me up as I made my buttons perfectly but ignored the 1px shadow/line around them, doh! :(

Edit: Just came across a really nice article/tutorial on the subject:

http://benfrain.com/how-to-serve-high-resolution-website-images-for-retina-displays-new-ipadiphone4/

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps the solution for a retina iPhone/iPad would work on a retina Mac. Indicate a higher resolution image such as:

```
background-image: url(your-image@2x.png);
```

Comment: Stackexchange isn't a site designed for guessing at answers

Comment: @ChrisBeach You ask a question, and then shoot down a possible solution because because I say "perhaps"?

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon Why wouldn't it work? DBUK's answer is essentially suggesting the same solution, but my answer gets -2...

Comment: The iOS framework has this facility, but web browsers don't have the @2x logic. Retinajs is using JavaScript to simulate the iOS behaviour. Your answer is simply wrong. You don't get points for guessing. In fact, you should lose points because you haven't even tried your proposed solution, and it could waste somebody else's time.

Comment: It’s not “basically the same solution” at all. RetinaJS is a script that allows that kind of approach to (kind of) work. You’re assuming native support (sans RetinaJS) for this behavior based on no apparent evidence.